# How would I get my pennies to double each loop?

Tags: java, math

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        
        //Variables
        int worked;
        double pennies,pay,totalpay;
            
        pay=0;
        totalpay=0.0;   
        pennies=0.01;
        //Scanner object for input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
        

        //Get days worked.
        System.out.println("How many days have you worked?");
        worked=keyboard.nextInt();
        
        //Display error and instruct to fix.
        while (worked < 1) 
        {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a number no less than one.");
        worked=keyboard.nextInt();
        }

        //Display the headings
        System.out.println("Days\t\tPennies");
        System.out.println("------------------------");
                
        //Display for Pennies * Days        
        for (int days=1; days <= worked; days++)
        {
            //The Math.
            totalpay+=pennies;
            pennies*=2;
            //Display
            System.out.printf(days+"\t\t$%,.2f\n",totalpay);
            
            
            if (days>=worked)
            System.out.printf("\n\nYour Total Pay is:\t$%,.2f",totalpay);
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

Class and package hidden for personal information reasons.

I've tried various different formulas to do the math but my math isn't mathing.

I need the penny value to double daily.
first day you'd make .01 second day you would make .02 third day you would make .04 fourth day .08 etcetcetc.

Every time I change the math in the program I just keep getting one crazy number after another.

(Java)

Comment: What is a "crazy" number? What's the type of `pennies`? What's the initial value? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: simply look closer. This sample is reproduceable if you make your own java project you literally have to copy pasta and import java.util. and a "crazy" number is any number other than the desired number... or a number that is not normal, or even out of the ordinary.

Comment: My bad, I missed the top of the method somehow. But it's still unclear what the problem is.

Comment: What's a "crazy" number? What numbers do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: The problem was that I was doing the math BEFORE i was displaying the first set of data. so no matter what variation I put for the math it was always wrong. I needed the pennies to double for each day like the old saying would you rather have x amount of money or a penny a day that doubled every day for a month. at the end of the month it would be like a couple million dollars. I had to write a program that the pennies doubled every day for however many days the user declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be very trivial but still I will go ahead and answer, looks like you dont even need to calculate `totalPay`, your `pennies` variable will hold the latest data for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    //Variables
    int worked;
    double pennies,pay,totalpay;
        
    pay=0;
    totalpay=0.0;   
    pennies=0.01;
    //Scanner object for input.
    //Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
    

    //Get days worked.
    System.out.println("How many days have you worked?");
    worked=20;
    
   
    //Display the headings
    System.out.println("Days\t\tPennies");
    System.out.println("------------------------");
            
    //Display for Pennies * Days        
    for (int days=1; days <= worked; days++)
    {
        //Display
        System.out.printf(days+"\t\t$"+pennies+"\n");
        pennies*=2;
        
        
        if (days>=worked)
        System.out.printf("\n\nYour Total Pay is:\t$%,.2f",totalpay);
        
    }
    
}
```

This will work well till some 30 days, after that scientific notations will start getting printed, you might want to use a BigDecimal for supporting larger number of days.

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you I had to tweak it a little; however, very useful and I see that a lot of the issue I was having was that I mathed the math before printing the first value. I should have printed the value and then mathed the math and THEN looped back. 

Also, total pay will be calculated before pennies multiply, because we need to display all the cumulative "pennies" at the end. ANYWAYS have good day.